# Using a shortcode to create a dropdown menu from wp_nav_menu list items

Tags: menus, shortcode, dropdown

I'm using the following function that I found online to render each page's individual nav items to the page:

```
function print_menu_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(
        shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'name' => null, 
                'class' => null
            ), 
            $atts
        )
    );

    return wp_nav_menu(
        array(
            'menu' => $name, 
            'menu_class' => $class, 
            'echo' => false
        )
    );
}
```

I would like to display these nav links in a dropdown menu with a button labeled *Menu* instead of just having the links render as an `ul`, but I don't know how to access the individual items within `wp_nav_menu`.

Any help would be the best, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**wp_get_nav_menu_items()**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/) which retrieves all menu items of a navigation menu.
Your shortcode callback should be something like this .

```
  function print_menu_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
       extract( shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'name' => null, 
                'class' => null
            ), 
            $atts
        ));

        // Assuming $name contains slug or  name of menue
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($name); 

        // Sample Output. Adjsut as per your exact requirements.

        // Sample Output variable.
        $menu_dropdown  = '';

        if ($menu_items){

            $menu_dropdown  .= '<select onChange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">';

            foreach( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {

               $link = $menu_item->url;
               $title = $menu_item->title;
               $menu_dropdown  .= '<option value="' . $link .'">'. $title . '</option>' ;

            }

             $menu_dropdown  .= '</select>';

        } else {
           $menu_dropdown  = '<!-- no menu defined in location "'.$theme_location.'" -->';
        }

           return $menu_dropdown ;
}
```

[**More Examples**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/#user-contributed-notes) on use of this function.